# How to extract only certain sections of an input text using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

This problem is quite simple, but I'm pretty lost here.

Input text:

> 'Less/RBR than/IN 1/2/CD of/IN all/DT US/NNP businesses/NNS are/VBP
>   sole/JJ proprietorships/NNS ?/.'

The code:

```
def get_words(pos_sent):
# Your code goes here
    s = ""
    x = re.findall(r"\b(\w*?)/\w*?\b", pos_sent)
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        s = s + " " + x[i]
    return s

def get_noun_phrase(pos_sent):
    # Penn Tagset
    # Adjetive can be JJ,JJR,JJS
    # Noun can be NN,NNS,NNP,NNPS
    t = get_words(pos_sent)
    regex = r'((\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN))'
    return re.findall(regex, t)
```

The first part simply removes the part of speech tags and the second is supposed to take that and use it to find the noun phrases.

It's supposed to output:

```
[’all US businesses’, ’sole proprietorships’]
```

but instead it outputs an empty list:

```
[]
```

Now, I can change it to take in the original tagged sentence, and I get:

```
[('all/DT US/NN', 'all/DT ', '', '', 'US/NN'), ('businesses/NN', '', '', '', 'businesses/NN'), ('sole/JJ proprietorships/NN', '', 'sole/JJ ', '', 'proprietorships/NN')]
```

which does have all the right bits, but it also has a whole bunch of other stuff in it that I don't want.

I'm still very new to regex, so I'm probably missing something stupid.

Comment: Not sure if regex is the best approach here, but I may be wrong >.>

Comment: You should indent your code properly. There's help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you need it.

Comment: It's pretty easy to match only the single sentence you've provided but it would break down if you tried to parse other texts that don't fit the pattern. E.g. to match "all/DT US/NNP businesses/NNS", you could write `"\S+/DT \S+/NNP \S+/NNS"`, do a `replace` or `translate` on the output and you're done. However, don't you also want to match "all/DT businesses/NNS"? Something tells me you'd need a trie or a graph and some recursion to step through the string and decide if the next word/tag is a valid node. If yes, make it the new starting node and repeat/recurse. If no, return the path/sentence.

Comment: I mean, what I have does work, kind of: It outputs this: [('all/DT US/NN', 'all/DT ', '', '', 'US/NN'), ('businesses/NN', '', '', '', 'businesses/NN'), ('sole/JJ proprietorships/NN', '', 'sole/JJ ', '', 'proprietorships/NN')] Which has all the parts.

Answer (score 0):

For your first function, use the following regex - `\b([0-9A-z\/]*)\/\w*?\b` - so you can ensure that "1/2" will stay as `1/2`, and not as `1 2` (along with improved formatting of outputted text):

```
import re

string = 'Less/RBR than/IN 1/2/CD of/IN all/DT US/NNP businesses/NNS are/VBP sole/JJ proprietorships/NNS ?/.'

def create_relationship(pos_sent):
    # Get all the words individually
    words = re.findall(r'\b([0-9A-z\/]*)\/\w*?\b', pos_sent)
    # ['Less', 'than', '1/2', 'of', 'all', 'US', 'businesses', 'are', 'sole', 'proprietorships']

    # Get all the tags individually
    penn_tag = re.findall(r'\b[0-9A-z\/]*\/(\w*)?\b', pos_sent)
    # ['RBR', 'IN', 'CD', 'IN', 'DT', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'NNS']

    # Create a relationship between the words and penn tag:
    relationship = []
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        relationship.append([words[i],penn_tag[i]])

    # [['Less', 'RBR'], ['than', 'IN'], ['1/2', 'CD'], ['of', 'IN'], ['all', 'DT'], 
    # ['US', 'NNP'], ['businesses', 'NNS'], ['are', 'VBP'], ['sole', 'JJ'], ['proprietorships', 'NNS']]

    return relationship


def get_words(pos_sent):
    # Pass string into relationship engine
    array = create_relationship(pos_sent)

    # Start with empty string
    s = ''

    # Conduct loop to combine string
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        # index 0 has the words
        s = s + array[i][0] + ' '

    # Return the sentence
    return s

def get_noun_phrase(pos_sent):
    # Penn Tagset
    # Adjetive can be JJ,JJR,JJS
    # Noun can be NN,NNS,NNP,NNPS
    # Noun Phrase must be made of: DT+RB+JJ+NN+PR (http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/mbsp-tags)

    # Pass string into relationship engine
    array = create_relationship(pos_sent)
    bucket = array
    output = []

    # Find the last instance of NN where the next word is not "NN"
    # For example, NNP VBP qualifies. In the case of NN NNP VBP, then
    # the correct instance is NNP. To do this, we need to loop and use
    # a bucket to capture what we need. The bucket will shirnk as we 
    # shrink the array to capture what we want

    noun = True

    # Keep doing this until there is no instances of Nouns
    while noun:

        # Would be ideal to have an if condition to see if there's a noun
        # in the first place to stop this form working (and avoiding errors)
        for i in range(0, len(bucket)):
            if re.match(r'(NN.*)',bucket[i][1]):
                # Set position of last noun
                last_noun = i

        noun_phrase = []

        # If we don't have noun, it'll stop the while loop
        if last_noun < 0:
            noun = False
        else:
            # go backwards from the point where you found the last noun
            for x in range(last_noun, -1, -1):
                # The penn tag must match any of these conditions
                if re.match(r'(NN.*|DT.*|JJ.*|RB.*|PR.*)',bucket[x][1]):
                    # if there is a match, then let's build the word
                    noun_phrase.append(bucket[x][0])
                    bucket.pop(x)
                else:
                    last_noun = -1
                    break

        # Make sure noun phrase isn't empty
        if noun_phrase:
            # Collect the noun phrase
            output.append(" ".join(reversed(noun_phrase)))

    # Fix the reverse issue
    return [i for i in reversed(output)]

print get_noun_phrase(string)
# ['all US businesses', 'sole proprietorships']
```

Comment: I mean, what I have does work, kind of: It outputs this: [('all/DT US/NN', 'all/DT ', '', '', 'US/NN'), ('businesses/NN', '', '', '', 'businesses/NN'), ('sole/JJ proprietorships/NN', '', 'sole/JJ ', '', 'proprietorships/NN')] Which has all the parts.

Comment: @BNSlug Do you have any additional use cases or examples and what their output would look like?

Comment: I mean, maybe I could find some. Is a noun phrase not a common term?

Comment: @BNSlug If you don't mind expanding why the output becomes `[’all US businesses’, ’sole proprietorships’]`. In other words, how should the program know when to combine (or break) the sentence?

Comment: @BNSlug It seems this site has what you need in terms of defining regex for Noun Phrases: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Comment: @BNSlug I think I've solved it using some logic and regex